# How to add image roles programmatically in products Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, role

I am creating products programmatically. I am using below code to add product image.. Images are adding perfectly fine.. but image roles are not showing. Can anyone please help me to add image roles in product images programmatically.

```
$c_product = $ob->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
if(file_exists($image1))
    $c_product->addImageToMediaGallery($image1, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
```

Comment: What result come in `$image1` varriable ?

Comment: it gives image path. Image is adding in product.. image role is not showing.. that's my issue..

Comment: yes - try with this `$c_product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    $dir->getPath('media').$image1,
    null,
    false,
    false
);`

Comment: I'm amused how adding images with `addImageToMediaGallery` is working for you. I had to do work arounds for it to work.

Comment: By the way do the images roles already exist?

Comment: No.. image roles are not showing

Comment: @Keerthana have you read my comments?

Comment: I have the same problem. $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id_product); $_product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, true); $_product->save(); the roless are not seted

Comment: @Keerthana is this resolved? I too face same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use following code to add/remove image from product in Magento2. 
// Instance of object manager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
*Remove Images From Product*/
$productId = ; // Id of product
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$productRepository->save($product);
/*Add Images To The Product*/
$imagePath = "sample.png"; // path of the image
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
$product->save();
```